# UPDATE 2 columns of a table of values from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have these 2 tables

```
Table P

A     | B    | C     | D       
-----------------------------
'abc' | NULL | 'kkk' | NULL
'xyz' | NULL | 'www' | NULL
'pqr' | NULL | 'ccc' | NULL


Table Q

X     | Y
-----------------------------
'abc' | 123
'xyz' | 12
'pqr' | 34
```

I need to update Table P column B and D with the value of Y from Table Q as long as the column A and C in Table P matches values of column X in Table Q.

My UPDATE now:

```
UPDATE TableP 
SET B = Q.Y
FROM TableQ Q (NOLOCK)
WHERE Q.X = A

UPDATE TableP 
SET D = Q.Y
FROM TableQ Q (NOLOCK)
WHERE Q.X = C
```

I only know how to do it in 2 UPDATE statements, how do I do this in a single UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`UPDATE FROM JOIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx):

```
UPDATE p
SET B = q1.Y,        --COALESCE(q1.Y, p.B) if needed
    D = q2.Y         --COALESCE(q2.Y, p.D)
FROM TableP p
LEFT JOIN TableQ q1
  ON p.A = q1.X
LEFT JOIN TableQ q2
  ON p.C = q2.X;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424411)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════╦═════╦═══╗
║  A  ║  B  ║  C  ║ D ║
╠═════╬═════╬═════╬═══╣
║ abc ║ 123 ║ kkk ║   ║
║ xyz ║  12 ║ www ║   ║
║ pqr ║  34 ║ ccc ║   ║
╚═════╩═════╩═════╩═══╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `UPDATE` from `Join` syntax

```
UPDATE p
SET B = case when Q.X = p.a then Q.Y else B end,
    D = case when Q.X = p.c then Q.Y else D end
FROM TableP p
INNER JOIN TableQ Q
  ON Q.X  in (p.A,p.C)
```

Comment: @StevenYong - Yes If B or D is already `NULL`. It can handled through ISNULL function

Comment: When all values in column A and C from Table P exist in column X of Table Q, some of the columns are NULL. Say 'kkk', 'www', 'ccc' are all in Table Q too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   UPDATE TableP 
   SET B = CASE WHEN Q.X = A THEN Q.Y ELSE B END,
       D = CASE WHEN Q.X = C THEN Q.Y ELSE D END
   FROM TableQ Q (NOLOCK)
```

However, I have missed the join. So This is my updated solution

```
   UPDATE TableP 
   SET B = CASE WHEN Q.X = A THEN Q.Y ELSE B END,
       D = CASE WHEN Q.X = C THEN Q.Y ELSE D END
   FROM TableQ Q (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN TableP P
   ON P.A = Q.X
```

Comment: You are missing a join with TableP in that statement.